# Como filtrar en una vista de power apps del registro más actual al mas viejo

Tags: powerapps

estoy trabajado en power apps y la apps se trata de insertar datos una lista de ShairPoint, pero cuando muestro los datos en un DataTable quiero que me muestre los más recientes
ejemplo

--Caso1--   ---Caso2--
ID Nombre  ID Nombre
1  Joseph  1  Joseph
2  Mario

Quiero que "Mario" se muestre primero ya que ese es registro mas reciente

Saludos y espero alguien me pueda ayudar

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: okk, disculpa, estoy haciendo una app para ir ingresando información a una base de datos en power apps y muestro la base de datos en la misma app para que los usuarios, vean la información.  bueno a la hora que esta muestro toda la información, la tabla me pone los registros actuales hasta el final y es algo molestoso para el usuario dar scrol hasta abajo y el los quiere ver al principio